# how do i change my int to something that is iterable?

Tags: python, iteration

Question is to get this output :
Run 1

```
Enter number of aisles in supermarket: 100
Enter the aisle number to visit: 1
Enter the aisle number to visit: 8
Enter the aisle number to visit: 5
Enter the aisle number to visit: 4
Enter the aisle number to visit: 10
Enter the aisle number to visit: 0
The minimum distance is 26 units
```

my code so far is

```
numberAisles = int(input("Enter number of Aisles in supermarket:"))
aisles = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit:"))
if aisles == 0:
    print ("Not visiting any aisle")
else:
    while aisles > 0:
        aisles = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit:"))
        if aisles == 0:
            iter (aisles)
            maxaisle = max(aisles)
            minaisle = min(aisles)
            B = (maxaisle + minaisle)//2
            minDis = ((maxaisle - B) + (B-minaisle))*2
            print (f"The minimum distance is {minDis} units")
```

Error message is "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: how can you get `max` of a number? `max` can be determined from a set of numbers, right?

Comment: What is the logic of iterating over an integer when it value is 0?

Comment: Create an empty list, add each aisle to the list and then iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

Please make some change in your code to work with list and its methods:

```
numberAisles = int(input("Enter number of Aisles in supermarket: "))
aisles = []
aisles.append(int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: ")))

i = 0
if aisles[0] == 0:
    print ("Not visiting any aisle")
else:
    while aisles[i] > 0:
        i += 1
        aisles.append(int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit: ")))
        if aisles[i] == 0:
            iter (aisles)
            maxaisle = max(aisles)
            minaisle = min(aisles)
            # B = (maxaisle + minaisle)//2
            # minDis = ((maxaisle - B) + (B-minaisle))*2
            minDis = ((maxaisle-minaisle))*2
            print (f"The minimum distance is {minDis} units")
```

No need of defining `B` here as two commented line equivalent to `((maxaisle-minaisle))*2`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of maxaisle and minaisle inside the loop but do the dis calc outside. Makes the code much cleaner.

```
maxaisle = 0
minaisle = 0
aisle = 1
numberAisles = int(input("Enter number of Aisles in supermarket:"))
while aisle > 0:
    aisle = int(input("Enter the aisle number to visit:"))
    maxaisle = max(maxaisle, aisle)
    minaisle = min(minaisle, aisle)

minDis = (maxaisle - minaisle)*2
if minDis == 0:
    print ("Not visiting any aisles")
else:
    print (f"The minimum distance is {minDis} units")
```